# SimpleDateFormat in UTC to String in given format

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, simpledateformat

I need add something to this line:

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss").format(new Date()).toUpperCase();
```

because I need time from UTC, not from my current location. Could you please help me?

Comment: I suggest setting the timezone if you want a particular timezone. I also suggest using the JSR-310 API added to Java 8 instead as it handles timezone much cleaner.  Note: `hh` is 12 hour time so you need to add `aa` for AM/PM or use `HH` for 24 hour time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use this:

```
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

or have a look at java8 LocalDateTime and DateTimeFormat API. java.util.Date and especially SimpleDateFormat are kinda outdated and I would recommend against using SimpleDateFormat if possible as it is not thread save which may bite you when using streams or something.

Java 8 alternative:

```
String now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss"));
```

Comment: Nope. After import java.util.TimeZone; IntellJ give messages 'Cannot resolve symbol getTimeZone' and 'Cannot resolve symbol setTimeZone'

Comment: What JDK Version are you using? It should work. I don't know intelliJ at least in Eclipse this works. Try cleaning or refreshing the project or something. Else try the Java8 version.

Comment: Ok, it works, but only if I write it in any function. If I try write this directly in class (like my first string), I have errors.

Comment: Yes because you can't do stuff on instances in direct class body. I recommend using the Java8 version if possible.